# Can I replace laptop screen with a lower resolution one?

Tags: laptop, installation, display, resolution, hp-elitebook

Recently I purchased an HP EliteBook 8570w workstation, which has a native resolution of 1920×1080, but unfortunately due to this high resolution everything is too small, especially the toolbars and icons.

I tried to customize window colors and appearance by increasing text size and icons sizes but it didn't reflect on some of my applications like AutoCAD; moreover, some texts are dislocated from their normal locations.

However, when I tried to change the resolution to 1366×768, everything is OK except that I lose image quality and the screen looks blurry.

Now I'm seriously thinking of replacing my laptop's screen with a lower resolution one (say, 1366×768). Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. All of them will be fairly expensive.

### Sourcing Parts

#### Through the Manufacturer

If the manufacturer (HP) sells your same laptop model with different screen resolutions, you should be able to purchase, via the manufacturer or through a reseller / parts vendor, a lower resolution panel.

#### Through a Secondary Source

If you can find out exactly the dimensions of your screen, subtracting the plastic trimming, as well as what physical interface it uses to connect to the laptop, you might be able to build yourself a solution that works well enough. Your best bet is to figure out where your manufacturer sources their parts from -- laptop builders often buy their LCDs pre-made by the pallet load from manufacturers -- and see if they have anything in the same size but a different resolution.

### Getting The Work Done

#### Do It Yourself

You can do it yourself if you have the tools, know-how, and fine motor control of your hands. You will probably need a (small) torque screw driver, a static guard, and a detailed hardware maintenance manual for your laptop model, with detailed instructions on how to take apart and put back together the components in the right order.

#### Professional Repair

Most likely, there is a repair shop that is an official partner of HP in your area. You can either drop off the laptop in person or mail it to them and have them perform the installation of the replacement panel. Depending on the shop policy, you might be able to purchase the LCD separately and ask them to install it, or they might require that you allow them to source the part themselves and install it. This will probably be very expensive, but you're practically guaranteed that the result will "work" and it won't fall apart or anything.

I'm not sure why you think the lower resolution is blurry. If it's in the same aspect ratio, it shouldn't be blurry. A lower resolution LCD is probably not going to be sharper; the higher resolution LCDs are typically more expensive, higher quality panels with a brighter, crisper, more responsive output. So I am confused that you think that it would be better to go with a worse part, when for the most part your display's scaling (or the scaling of your GPU) should do a good job.

### Scaling...

On the topic of scaling -- have you tried toggling (enabling if it's disabled, or disabling if it's enabled) the GPU scaling feature of your GPU? Scaling to non-native resolutions can be done either by the GPU or by the display itself; the quality varies. You might want to try both modes before deciding that it's too blurry for you to use.

Discussion on scaling display vs. gpu [here](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=344575)

More info [here](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1616601)

Comment: thanks allquixotic indeed , i think my problem is that since my current screen has a native resolution of 1920 x 1080 then it will offer the best image quality with a very very small text & icons , however if i try to change this NATIVE resolution to 1366 x 768 then everything is blurry with a normal text & icons sizes. on the other hand if i replace the screen with another one which has a NATIVE resolution of 1366 x 768 then this will offer best image quality  while all texts and icons and toolbars will be proportional as desired , that's why im thinking to replace this screen.

Comment: Note that 1920x1080 and 1366x768 have identical aspect ratios; that is, the ratio between the horizontal and the vertical is the same (16:9). Try dividing 1920 by 16 and 1080 by 9, then divide 1366 by 16 and 768 by 9. They're (very nearly) the same aspect ratio. So the *proportionality* of the screen between a native 1366x768 and a 1920x1080 will be almost the same.